# Strange behavior of NumberForm with ScientificNotationThreshold option inside Dynamic

Tags: dynamic, output-formatting

Using the ScientificNotationThreshold option inside NumberForm causes erroneous behavior and generates a mystifying error message when used inside Dynamic.

For example, running

```
With[{x = N[-\[Pi] 10^4]},
 Print[{
   NumberForm[x],
   NumberForm[x, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-3, 3}]
   }];
 Grid[{{
    Dynamic[NumberForm[x], (x = #) &],
    Dynamic[
     NumberForm[x, 
      ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-3, 3}], (x = #) &]},
   {InputField[
     Dynamic[Style[NumberForm[x], 
       ShowStringCharacters -> False], (x = #) &], FieldSize -> 5, 
     Alignment -> Right],
    InputField[
     Dynamic[Style[
       NumberForm[x, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-3, 3}], 
       ShowStringCharacters -> False], (x = #) &], FieldSize -> 5, 
     Alignment -> Right]}
   }]
 ]
```

produces this output

[image]

accompanied by the twice repeated error message

> NumberForm::expons: The value ScientificNotationThreshold of the
> option {-3,3} should be a list of two values. Each can be a machine
> integer or +/- Infinity.

In the example, NumberForm is invoked three times

1. Not inside Dynamic
2. Inside Dynamic, and
3. Inside an InputField that contains a Dynamic argument

and each one is done two different ways, once WITHOUT and once WITH the ScientificNotationThreshold option explicitly set.

The error occurs only when I try to explicitly set the ScientificNotationThreshold option inside Dynamic.

Even the statement of the error seems slightly backward.

What's going on here?

Seems like a bug in Mathematica to me.

Is there a simple way to make this work the way it's supposed to?

Note: I included the two cases that use InputField merely to show the type of code I actually intend to use and why Dynamic is necessary for my purposes.

Comment: Pink boxes no longer appear in 13.1.

Answer (score 1):

This bug still persists in Mathematica 12.3.

## Workaround

Define

```
ToRawBoxesQuiet[value_] := Quiet[RawBoxes[ToBoxes[value]]]
```

and use the function before calling `Dynamic`:

```
Dynamic[ToRawBoxesQuiet[...]]
```

or `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
  ToRawBoxesQuiet[...],
  ...
]
```

## How I found the workaround

I used

```
Dynamic[NumberForm[1, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-4, 4}]]
```

as an example.

In the stack trace of the error there is the line

```
MakeBoxes[NumberForm[1, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-4, 4}], StandardForm]
```

so it seems like a bug of `MakeBoxes` **and** `NumberForm`. So I tried to manually create the boxes (using `ToBoxes`) and use `Quiet` to suppress the error message.